# SSL: crypto enabling timeout

Tags: wampserver, mantis

I am using latest version of WampServer with Apache 64bit 2.4.9, PHP 5.5.12. I am running MantisBT on it. Everything is running properly. However, everytime on the first email sending from MantisBT after PC clean bootup, I always got this error message:

```
SYSTEM WARNING: 'stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout' in 'C:\wamp\www\mantisbt\library\phpmailer\class.smtp.php' line 249
```

The first email will never send until I try to send any other email again, the first email will go through as well.

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the same warning, have you get the solution?

Comment: @CharlesRojas No, no solution at all.

Comment: Well I've searched a little (I tried it again and was ok so for me no problem, that makes me believe a problem in net) and get some possible causes: SMTP's service, firewall...